# Concatenating strings while using figure command (MATLAB)

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, matlab-figure, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate strings , when I concatenate them separately like this:

```
strcat({'Plot of f with a plot of iterates for c='},{int2str(c)})
```

no error comes.

But when I try to use them in figure command like this:

```
 figure('Name',strcat({'Plot of f with a plot of iterates for c='},{int2str(c)}))
```

I receive this error:

```
Error using figure
Value must be a string
```

Any reason for this?

Comment: You need to be aware of your data types. The output of `strcat` here is a cell because you are passing it cells. A cell is not a string. There's no reason to pass cells to `strcat` here.

Comment: As @excaza said. Also there is no need for `strcat`, you can use concatenation implicitely: `str = ['Plot of f with a plot of iterates for c=', int2str(c)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as pointed out by @Matthias W. the output of `strcat({'Plot of f with a plot of iterates for c='},{int2str(c)})` is a `1x1 cell`, not a string as expected by `figure()` function.

Try the following

`figure('Name',['Plot of f with a plot of iterates for c=', int2str(c)])`

Answer (score 1):

Using []s for string concatenation is a great short solution. Since you're already doing the conversion, you might also consider learning [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
figure('Name', sprintf('Plot of f with a plot of iterates for c = %d.\n', c));
```

This might be overkill in this example, but may be worth it if you need to print out a number of values, or want more control over how the numbers are displayed.